# Object has been deleted or invalidated [Realm-Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, realm

So i have 2 ViewControllers

1. MapStoreViewController
2. StoreListViewController

The flow is MapStoreViewController -> StoreListViewController

Inside the MapStoreViewController, I call an API and save the API to the realm

```
Alamofire.request(urlRequest, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseArray { (response: DataResponse<[OutletDTO]>) in
        /* Check for server response */
        var serverResponse = RestHelper.validateRequestResponse(response: response)
        if serverResponse.0 == true {
            if let responseObject = serverResponse.2 {

                /* Open realm */
                    let realm = try! Realm()
                    let realmOutlet = realm.objects(OutletDTO.self)

                    /* Delete all the object stored in realm if there is any */
                    try! realm.write {
                        realm.delete(realmOutlet)
                    }
                    /* Loop the array from the response object and add it to realm */
                    if responseObject.count > 0 {
                        for eachOutlet in responseObject {
                            try! realm.write {
                                realm.add(eachOutlet)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                serverResponse.2 = responseObject
                completion(serverResponse.0, serverResponse.1, serverResponse.2)
            }
        }
```

And then there is a bar button item on the MapStoreViewController that will redirect user to the StoreListViewController

IF the user directly move to StoreListViewController, after few seconds, the app will crash because of this Object invalidated error

In the StoreListViewController, i also call above API.

After tried to research on my flow. I found out that if i dont call the API function on my MapStoreViewController, the app wouldn't crash in the StoreListViewController.

If both VC tried to call the same API function which will also access the realm, the crash will happen.

Is it because of threading? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say it's because you delete every object in `realm.delete(realmOutlet)`

Comment: at which line are you getting the crash? are you querying `OutletDTO` anywhere else?